# Números e Percentual na string C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Minha string não está vindo com caracteres estranhos, está vindo com números e porcentagem. Exemplo:

```
"teste@test.com"
```

fica

```
"teste%40test.com"
```

ou

```
"fictício"
```

fica

```
"fict%C3%ADcio"
```

Comment: Vindo de onde? Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Esse é o escape utilizado na query string ou nos forms. Tem que fazer o unescape da string, normalmente isso é feito automáticamente.

Comment: Valder, você pode postar o seu código, de preferência no ponto onde você recupera e/ou imprime a `string`. Se possível, aproveita e dá mais detalhes do problema. Com isso, sua dúvida será respondida mais rapidamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver utilizando

```
Server.UrlDecode(minhaString);
```